# VPN tunnel in VPN tunnel

Tags: linux, vpn, tor

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to establish VPN tunnels through other VPN tunnels to get onion routing like properties (sender anonymity). Since VPN builds a tunnel, it should be easy to set up another tunnel in this tunnel to another VPN endpoint, but I have found no documentation on such a setup. It would be interesting to extend this to more than two hops...

**Why?**

Tor nodes are public and those IPs are often blocked and reveal that you are using Tor. There are many open VPN nodes and I hope not all of them are malicious, hence getting similar properties like Tor.

**Does anybody know of such a setup? Preferably using linux ;)**

Comment: Tor is constantly adding and dropping nodes to prevent anyone from doing what you are describing.

Answer (score 6):

Four simple-ish solutions I can think of are:

1. **proxychains** would work if you don't really need a VPN; or your other applications can talk SOCKS
2. **stunnel** needs a fair bit of setup
3. **OpenVPN** needs a lot of setup
4. **ssh** using -L or -D is trivial by comparison