# VPN Server Inside VPN client on Router

Tags: network, vpn, anonymity, virtualization, router

This is a different context of an already asked question:

- In a few words: Sub-VPN or VPN SubNetwork... VPNsception?

So I am using DD-WRT flashed router which connects as a client to VPN server "O_VPN".

Can I Have a machine inside my local Network running a VPN Server "I_VPN" to which I can connect to from outside my network.

Basically I want to have a secure SubNetwork inside the already existing VPN.

My main questions are:

1. Is it possible to connect to this Sub-VPN?
2. How can do it from the outside? (outside both VPNs)

Comment: Did you see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60871/vpn-tunnel-inside-other-vpn-tunnel ?

Comment: Yes i did, unfortunately is a different concept.
That one talks Connecting to a VPN while already inside another VPN.

My question is Creating a VPN Server while already inside a VPN kind of like creating a subnet of VPNs.

Thanks for your response. Really  appreciate it!

Comment: I'm looking into the same idea. Did you get anywhere with this?